# Prisma query from given table as parameter

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, prisma

I am trying to make a query in prisma that given a table received as parameter from an http request queries the first 100 rows from given table.

I am using the following query:

```
let rows = await prisma.$queryRawUnsafe\`SELECT * FROM ${collection} LIMIT 100\`;
```

However I receive the following error:

```
error - PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.$queryRaw()` invocation:


Raw query failed. Code: `42601`. Message: `db error: ERROR: syntax error on "$1"`
```

Comment: You realize that this might pose a huge security risk without using a whitelist for the tablename?

Comment: Should I use a switch statement to do this? Anyway this is not something a normal client will be able to do, it's on the admin side only.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to invoke the queryRawUnsafe method like this:

```
let collectionName = 'User'
let rows = await prisma.$queryRawUnsafe(`SELECT * FROM ${collectionName} LIMIT 100`)
```

Here's a reference to queryRawUnsafe method: [Documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#dynamic-table-names-in-postgresql)